# Apache / PHP - Rewrite rule within a sub-folder redirects to root folder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I want to just remove the extension of php files from the URL.

I am using CPanel to control virtual hosts on the server.

My php files which I want them to be accessed without the extension are located in "**folder2**". *Folder1* is a subdomain.

```
/public_html/folder1/folder2/file1.php
```

So I created a .htaccess file within folder2:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

But now when I try to access the link:
http://folder1.domain.com/folder2/file1

I get redirected to http://folder1.domain.com/file1 (Which is a 404).

What's wrong with the .htaccess? Is there anything I should enable on apache?

Comment: If it is a linux apache you have to hack it.

Comment: @timmyRS Would you care to elaborate that comment? Why? What for? What does this have to do with the OS?

Comment: You asked `Is there anything I should enable on apache?` and I kindly told you: If it happens to be a UNIX (or Linux) system, you need to hack it a bit. aka Yes, you have to enable something.